# Spring boot config client not resolving config server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-config-server

Config client cannot resolve configuration property and cannot connect to config server.
Here's my service application.properties file:

```
spring.application.name = idmanager-service
spring.cloud.config.uri = http://localhost:8888

server.port=8081

#enable actuator endpoints
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.health.show-details=always
info.app.name=Id management Application
info.app.description=managing citizens identities
info.app.version=0.1.0
```

The dependencies in pom.xml:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Lmobok Dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- / Lmobok Dependency-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <!--<version>RELEASE</version>-->
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Eureka discovery client-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Config client-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

The config server and the discovery server started successfully and other services are successfully registered.

Here's the config server application.properties file:

```
server.port=8888
spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=file:./src/main/resources/myConfig
```

The application.properties file in myConfig folder:

```
global=xxxxx
```

Other services are successfully registered and fetching config server:
`c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator : Fetching config from server at : http://localhost:8888`

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by fixing Spring cloud version like below:
`<spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR3</spring-cloud.version>`

Then I specified the Spring cloud dependency version using dependency management:

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```